# Services to help disabled travelers when travelling, eg with accommodation in Canary Islands and travel from Russia

Tags: international-travel, russia, accessibility, canary-islands

I'm disabled, from Russia. And I'm planning to travel in the future as much as I can. I'm seeking companies, services, which can to help me with accommodation, because I'm a wheelchair user.

Maybe here are some people, who knows about such service. I need someone, who will help with a delivery and, maybe, help in plane and road. I communicated with a one company in Italy. This is probably possible for them as I understood (I haven't talked with them directly yet). Maybe someone knows more about this.

I can add more details if needed.

Comment: I think it might be best if you broke this down into a few bits, eg "what are the disabled facilities like at <airport>", "what travel companies offer disabled friendly holidays in <location>". As it stands, there are too many different answers and we don't want just a huge list...

Comment: You might also want to read some [trip reports like this](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/trip-reports/1356883-you-travel-how-one-million-girl-rolls.html) to get an idea of what's possible. Decide where you'd like to go, and we can help you work out how to do it!

Comment: Thanks. Yes. As one of possible destinations I think about this place: http://www.marysol.org/. This is Los Cristianos in Canary islands. And to concrete my source - I'm from [Yaroslavl city, Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaroslavl).

Comment: I'd suggest you break that down into something like "what disabled friendly airlines fly from near Moscow to the Canary Islands", "what disabled friendly methods exist to get from Yaroslavl to <airport as suggested by airline choice>", "what are the disabled facilities like at <airport>", and "how to get from <canaries aiport> to <hotel area> in a wheelchair"

Comment: @Gagravarr, Okay. Need I create a separate question for each of them, or it'll be Okay if I'll edit this post?

Comment: The best fit for the StackExchange Q&A format would be to open one new question for each part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In response to your question there are very few companies worldwide who can actually provide a broadbased service for wheelchair users such as you seem to be seeking. The majority of specialist tour providers are based in the USA (5 agencies), Canada (2 agencies), UK (1 agency and around 4 holiday/vacation based tour operators), Spain (my company Disabled Accessible Travel), (Italy, 2 agencies).

The key issue for you is that most of these agencies specialise in cruise vacations or resort based vacations, NOT individual services for parts of travel such as just an accessible airport transfer or just reserving a hotel room with roll-in shower. You mention Italy so you have either been in touch with Accessible Europe or Accessible Italy, Accessible Europe will be able to assist with Italian based services and also Asia through their other accessible travel based company.

My own company, Disabled Accessible Travel offers a unique bespoke service to wheelchair users and we are happy to supply full or part services where they are possible in any one of 51 countries where we have suppliers. Feel free to email dat@disabledaccessibletravel.com with your requirements. We are based in Barcelona, Spain.

Comment: Hey Alan, and welcome to Travel-SE! We have some guidelines on promotion, see [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion). Promoting the services of your company is totally okay, but it's probably better to put your contact information [on your profile page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4174/alan-broadbent). Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

[Wheelmap.org](http://wheelmap.org) can be very useful for you. It contains POIs with information wheter there are accessible for wheelchair.

[Here](http://wheelmap.org/?zoom=7&lat=28.42995&lon=-16.96389&layers=BT) you have Canary Islands on Wheelmap (zoom in to see specific location with POIs).

The biggest disadvantage of this map is that still majority of POIs are not described.